# Dúvida com versão do AspNet.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

No meu packages.config eu tenho as seguinte configurações:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

O meu servidor de hospedagem mostra que tenho :

ASP.NET 4.5

MVC  5

Neste caso eu preciso altera a versão do meu AspNet.Mvc ? Se for necessário como fazer esta alteração?

Comment: Você já realizou um teste? Acredito que não terá problema nenhum. Qual hospedagem você está utilizando?

Comment: Já fiz a verificação, o framework  é 4.5, estou usando a vbmahospedagem.com.br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não.

Apenas certifique-se que seu projeto está exatamente nesta versão do *framework*, clicando com o botão direito no projeto e selecionando a opção *Properties*.

Se estiver na versão 4.5 do *framework* e o *build* não falha, o projeto está apto a subir neste ambiente.

Comment: Correto, o framework  é 4.5.